# How can i display the data of the selected row from the tableview in the detail view in a splitview controller?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I've managed to read some values into a table view and display them in the Master View of a SplitViewController.

What I would like to do is to tap on a row of the Master View and display the details on the detailViewController but in a TableView.

When I tap on the row in the MasterView table, I can't seem to get the detail to populate the detailview TableView.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do i need to take a separate "Ipad view with Controller" type file for the TableView (which is on the detailview) on which i want to display the detailed information or i need to create the subclass for this tableview in the detailcontroller.xib.cs file itself?    Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

- Add an outlet to your master view controller which is a link to your detail view controller
- Connect this outlet (either in Interface Builder or in code)
- Add properties to your detail view for the values you're interested in displaying
- in your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` retrieve the data for the selected row and set the corresponding properties in your detail view

Comment: Hi Denis, Can you be plz a bit more specific and clear as i am a novice in this field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read this basic tutorial.

http://doronkatz.com/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world

Go through the sample code and see what you are doing wrong or missing

EDIT: its a tutorial on splitViewController.

Answer (score 0):

may be this code is help for you

in table View  .m file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(self.dvController == nil){
    DetailsViewController *viewControoler = [[DetailsViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"detailsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.dvController = viewControoler;
    [viewControoler release];
}

DocumentNavController *docObjNew = [appdelegate.noteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[docObjNew hydrateDetailViewData];
//
dvcontroller.noteObj = docObjNew;  //noteobj reference  from in DetailsViewController.m file DocumentNavController *noteObj;

dvcontroller.currentindex = indexPath.row;


[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.dvController animated:YES];

self.dvController.title = [docObjNew noteTitle];
[self.dvController.noteTitelFiled setText:[docObjNew noteTitle]];
[self.dvController.notediscView setText:[docObjNew noteDisc]];



}
```

in table view .h file

```
@interface DocumentTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

UITableView *documenttableView;

evernoteAppDelegate *appdelegate;
UINavigationController *navControll;
DetailsViewController *dvcontroller;
DocumentNavController *docNavContro;

//NSIndexPath *selectIndexPath;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain)DetailsViewController *dvController;
@property (nonatomic, retain)DocumentNavController *docNavContro;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UITableView *documenttableView;
```

in DetailsViewController.h file

```
UITextField *noteTitelFiled;
UITextView *notediscView;

DocumentNavController *noteObj;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *noteTitelFiled;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextView *notediscView;
@property (nonatomic, retain)DocumentNavController *noteObj;
```